# Finding the min, max and average of a list in a txt file

Tags: python

the program must read the contents of input.txt, find the min, max and average and then print out the results in a new file.

here is my code so far

```
# to open the txt file in read and write mode
text_file = open('input.txt', 'r+')

# we now create a list for the numbers in the program
number_list = []

# now we create a loop that loops over each line in the txt file
for line in text_file:
    number_list.append(line.split(','))
```

Comment: The input input.txt reads

min:1,2,3,5,6
max:1,2,3,5,6
avg:1,2,3,5,6


and the output must read: 

The min of [1, 2, 3, 5, 6] is 1.
The max of [1, 2, 3, 5, 6] is 6.
The avg of [1, 2, 3, 5, 6] is 3.4.

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, you want to use a context manager like [with](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) to take care of opening and closing the file automatically

Then you can use python builtins [min](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) [max](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) and [sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) to calculate minimum, maximum and average respectively

```
#Open the txt file in read and write mode, and get all integers in file
number_list = []
with open('file.txt', 'r') as fp:
    number_list = [int(item) for item in fp.readlines()]

#Calculate minimum, maximum and average and print it
minimum = min(number_list)
maximum = max(number_list)
average = sum(number_list)/len(number_list)

print('min:', minimum, 'max:', maximum, 'avg:', average)
```

So if `input.txt` looks like this (one number per line):

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

The output will be

```
min: 1 max: 10 avg: 5.5
```

Comment: okay i understand what you mean. in my case the input input.txt reads 
min:1,2,3,5,6 
max:1,2,3,5,6 
avg:1,2,3,5,6 


and the output must read: 
The min of [1, 2, 3, 5, 6] is 1. 
The max of [1, 2, 3, 5, 6] is 6. 
The avg of [1, 2, 3, 5, 6] is 3.4 


how do i go about it when i need to print?

Comment: This file format is redundant since you are repeating information, why not choose a Format like I provided, which makes it much cleaner to read? @Larreth ? Also if you can paste your input file in the question, it will me much helpful!

Answer (score 0):

you need first to convert your array to int and then use max, min and sum, len functions :

```
number_list_int = [int(i) for i in number_list[0]]

print(min(number_list_int))
print(max(number_list_int))
print(sum(number_list_int)/len(number_list_int))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming file contains integer values separated by newline

```
>>> # Read file into an array and convert string form integers to int
>>> fd = open("nums")
>>> nums = map(int, fd.read().strip().splitlines())
>>> fd.close()
>>> nums
[12, 15, 5, 89, 2, 3, 5, 6, 11]

>>> # Following functions are self explanatory
>>> max(nums)
89
>>> min(nums)
2
>>> sum(nums)
148
>>> len(nums)
9

>>> # write to file
>>> fd = open("result", "w")
>>> fd.write("max: " + str(max(nums)))
>>> fd.write("\nmin: " + str(min(nums)))
>>> fd.write("\navg: " + str(sum(nums) / len(nums)))
>>> fd.close()
```